# What kind of error do I raise so my messages end up in the DLQ

Tags: apache-kafka-connect

I have what is likely an embarrassing question but I'm a bit lost.

I've read this article which I think is quite comprehensive about how KafkaConnect can handle DLQs.
https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-connect-deep-dive-error-handling-dead-letter-queues/

I set it up on my connector:

```
errors.tolerance: all
errors.log.enable: true
errors.log.include.messages: false
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.name: com.kafkaconnect.jdbc.dlq
errors.deadletterqueue.topic.replication.factor: 1
errors.deadletterqueue.context.headers.enable: true
```

However I experience 2 things:
First my DLQ is always empty.
Second if I have an error in one of the topics I am processing simply everything stops and the connector just goes into error mode.

I first want to ask about my assumption:
My assumption would be messages that I can send to the DLQ are messages that fail, either the ValueConverter or the KeyConverter processing. This would be my expectation.

Second, what kind of error during the ValueConverter can be invoked so that the task/connector continues processing the other messages but the error message goes into the DLQ.

At the moment my code for failures in the ValueConverter look like this, and this makes basically the connector explode instead of sending the messages to the DLQ.

```
  public SchemaAndValue toConnectData(String topic, Headers headers, byte[] value) {
    try {
      Object deserialized = this.deserializer.deserialize(topic, value);

      if (deserialized == null) {
        return SchemaAndValue.NULL;
      } else if (deserialized instanceof Message) {
        Message message = (Message) deserialized;
        return this.protobufData.toConnectData(message.getDescriptorForType(), message, topic);
      }
      throw new DataException(String.format(
          "Unsupported type returned during deserialization of topic %s ",
          topic
      ));
    } catch (SerializationException e) {
      throw new DataException(String.format(
          "Failed to deserialize data for topic %s to Protobuf: ",
          topic
      ), e);
    }
  }
```

I know this is not a small reproduceable scenario of the problem, but honestly I don't know how to create one easily. I'm more wondering for people with experience in using KafkaConnectors how do you normally implement it so that the messages that fail on the deserialization end up in the DLQ.

Thank you for any feedback.

Comment: Miguel did you find a solution for your issue? I having the same and struggling

Comment: I think this was a miss configuration on my part. I now manage to have everything on the DLQ but honestly I don't like how the Kafka connect framework handles errors because I can't diffentiate easily that only converter errors go into the queue. Every error (even connectivity) end up in the DLQ which is not great